# How can I tell if a vendored gem is being used?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems

I have inherited an old project that was previously passed on by multiple developers. It's in a bad shape so I'm trying to bring it back to life. I notice there are some gems and libs that have been vendored into the project but can't tell if they are being used or what!

How can I workout if some of those gems are no longer being used by the project?

Comment: remove them and see if anything breaks

Comment: @NickGinanto I was hoping there would be a more elegant way.

Comment: the only other way I know is to see if the code uses those gems the hard way.. searching for core things of the gem in the code manually

Comment: The answer is probably 'No', but in any case, does the app have a good test suite? If yes, then it would make it easier to confidently remove stuff by ensuring the test suite still runs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A convenient way of checking this is by using a REPL. I would recommend installing the [pry-rails](https://github.com/rweng/pry-rails) gem, which will simply replace the default rails console (IRB) with the arguably more powerful [Pry REPL](http://pryrepl.org/).

```
#Gemfile

group :development do
  pry-rails
end
```

Run `bundle install`, and than start the Rails console with `bundle exec rails c`. Once you are within Pry, you can use its built in `show-source` command to look up where a specific method has been implemented. Example:

```
 >> show-source ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection

 From: /home/andrea/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb @ line 128:
 Owner: #<Class:ActiveRecord::Base>
 Visibility: public
 Number of lines: 11

 def self.establish_connection(spec = ENV["DATABASE_URL"])
   resolver = ConnectionSpecification::Resolver.new spec, configurations
   spec = resolver.spec

   unless respond_to?(spec.adapter_method)
     raise AdapterNotFound, "database configuration specifies nonexistent #   {spec.config[:adapter]} adapter"
   end
   remove_connection
   connection_handler.establish_connection name, spec
 end
```

For more usage examples on how to use this specific built-in command, refer to Pry's inline `help` system:

```
   help show-source
```

Or have a look at the [Source browsing](https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/Source-browsing#wiki-Show_method) page, on Pry's wiki.

Answer (score 1):

there are some simple tricks that help you do that. you could for example put an `puts caller` i the root files of the gems and see if they get called from somewhere.

you could also use tracing functionality built into ruby like: http://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/set_trace_func

or use external tracing tools.